# return objects pointing to other objects in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a model UserSelect

```
class UserSelect(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
bowler = models.ForeignKey(Bowlers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='bowlers', null=True, blank=True)
batsman = models.ForeignKey(Batsmen, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='batsman', null=True, blank=True)
team = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default='1')
```

which is pointing to my two models bowler and batsman using foreign key

I am calling this model values in my view as

```
def team(request, pk):
user_sel = UserSelect.objects.filter(user=request.user, team=pk)
context = {
    'user_sel': user_sel,
}
return render(request, 'team_analysis.html', context)
```

here I am getting all objects by giving pk but how do I access data of my other two models bowler and batsman through it in views?

Comment: Are you trying to access `Bowlers` and `Batsmen` related to current filter condition (ie, `filter(user=request.user, team=pk)`) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access them in views like this:

```
for user in user_sel:
    print(user.bowler) # bowler model object
    print(user.batsman) # batsman model object
```

Also you can access them in templates as well:

```
{% for user in user_sel %}
    {{ user.bowler }}
    {{ user.bowler.pk }}
    {{ user.batsman }}
    {{ user.batsman.pk }}
{% endfor %}
```